# JavaScript using DOM

Tags: javascript

I need help with a JavaScript code here are the directions and what I have so far...

I need to use DOM manipulation to get the Tic Tac Toe game to work. 
Here are the directions provided:

1. To make sure nothing happens when the user clicks on a square that
   already contains a marker:

   - remove the onclick attribute from the clicked TD element in the 
     squareClicked function.
   - add the onclick attribute to each TD when setting a new game
   - remove the onclick attribute from the each TD that has a marker
     when loading a game.
2. Modify the squareClicked function so that it will:

   - make sure the square does not have an X or O in it
   - determine which player's turn it is
   - create a new DIV element with the correct class and place it in the 
     clicked TD (don't use innerHTML)
   - change the current player
3. In the setBanner function, check to see if a banner has already been set
   and delete the old one before setting the new one.

Not looking for any solutions.. just a guide on how to get the code to function properly.

```js
// set the class name of the player who will start
document.getElementById('X').className = 'current-player';
document.getElementById('O').removeAttribute('class');

// this will run when the page loads
function init() {
 var game = [[1,3,5,8],[4,6,7,2]];
 // find the tbody element. It is there even though we did not put it in our HTML.
 var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
 // row is a single row element. We will step through the rows in the outer while loop.
 var row = tbody.firstChild;
 var td;
 while(row) {
  console.log(row.nodeName);
  // td is a single td element. We will step through each td in this row in the inner while loop.
  td = row.firstChild;
  while(td) {
   if(td.tagName === 'TD') {
    console.log('Found a TD');
    td.setAttribute('onclick', 'squareClicked(this);');
   }
   td = td.nextSibling;
  }
  row = row.nextSibling;
 }
 loadGame(game);
 // Step 3: add a "Set Banner" button
 var newGameButton = document.querySelector('#players input');
 var setBannerButton = document.createElement('input');
 setBannerButton.setAttribute('type', 'button');
 setBannerButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'setBanner();');
 setBannerButton.setAttribute('value', 'Set Banner');
 
 newGameButton.parentNode.insertBefore(setBannerButton,newGameButton);
}

// reset the board when the "New Game" button is clicked
function newGame() {
 // create a NodeList of all the td elements, again.
 // We could make tdNodes a global variable so we don't have to recreate it.
 // Here I use a different method.
 var tdNodes = document.querySelectorAll('td');
 var removeNode;
 for(var i=0; i<tdNodes.length; i++) {
  // clear the content of each node
  //tdNodes[i].innerHTML = '';
  // Step 2: instead of innerHTML, we will use DOM manipulation 
  removeNode = tdNodes[i].firstChild;
  if(removeNode) {
   removeNode.parentNode.removeChild(removeNode);
  }
 }
}

function squareClicked(sqr) {
 // show an alert. As a bonus we show which square was clicked.
 alert('You clicked square ' + sqr.id);
}

function loadGame(state) {
 var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
 // row is a single row element. We will step through the rows in the outer while loop.
 var row = tbody.firstChild;
 var td;
 var newEl;
 while(row) {
  console.log(row.nodeName);
  // td is a single td element. We will step through each td in this row in the inner while loop.
  td = row.firstChild;
  while(td) {
   if(td.tagName === 'TD') {
    console.log('Found a TD');
    idNum = td.id;
    idNum = idNum.replace('c', ''); // Remove the c at the beginning.
    idNum = parseInt(idNum); // Convert it to a number.
    // Check to see if it is in the X array, state[0]
    if(state[0].indexOf(idNum) > -1){
     //td.innerHTML = '<div class="X-marker"></div>';
     // Step 1: instead of innerHTML, we will use DOM manipulation 
     newEl = document.createElement('DIV');
     newEl.className = 'X-marker';
     td.appendChild(newEl);
    }
    // Check to see if it is in the O array, state[1]
    if(state[1].indexOf(idNum) > -1){
     //td.innerHTML = '<div class="O-marker"></div>';
     // Step 1 again
     newEl = document.createElement('DIV');
     newEl.className = 'O-marker';
     td.appendChild(newEl);
    }
   }
   td = td.nextSibling;
  }
  row = row.nextSibling;
 }
}

// Step 4: setBanner function
//    - Prompt the user to input a title for the game.
//    - Create an h1 element to contain this input.  
//    - Securely (careful of HTML) insert the input into the h1 element and add it to 
//     the page immediately after the opening body tag.
function setBanner() {
 var banner = prompt('Banner Text?');
 var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
 h1.textContent = banner;
 //var body = document.querySelector('body');
 var playerDiv = document.querySelector('#players');
 //insertBefore (newNode, referenceNode)
 document.body.insertBefore(h1, playerDiv);
}
```

```html
<body onload="init();">  
<div id="players">
 <div id="X" class="">Player X</div>
 <div id="O" class="">Player O</div>
 <input type="button" class="button" value="New Game" onclick="newGame()"/>
</div>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td id="c0"></td>
  <td id="c1"></td>
  <td id="c2"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="c3"></td>
  <td id="c4"></td>
  <td id="c5"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="c6"></td>
  <td id="c7"></td>
  <td id="c8"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide some sample html and make a JSfiddle so people can help you more easily.

Comment: Please give your question a title describing the problem. Also, please pare down your sample code to no more than a few dozen lines.

Comment: Where did you get those directions from? You definitely should not use the `onclick` attribute at all.

Comment: What part(s) of the code are not "working properly"?

Comment: You say your code is not functioning properly... what aspect of it is not working? Does it not run at all? does it get hung up at some point? does it give you incorrect output?

Answer (score 1):

There is code for Tic Tac Toe game I made in js long time ago :)

```js
window.onload = function() {
 initXO();
}

function initXO() {
 var tbl=document.getElementById('xo');
 for(var i=0;i<3;i++) {
  var row=tbl.insertRow();
  for(var x=0;x<3;x++) {
   var cell=row.insertCell();
   cell.innerHTML='';
   cell.setAttribute('onclick','xoCheck(this);');
  }
 }
}

function xoCheck(ele) {
 if (document.getElementById('ovr').value=='0') {
  var row=ele.parentNode;
  var red=document.getElementById('red');
  var br=(row.rowIndex*3)+(ele.cellIndex+1);
  var pl;
  if(ele.innerHTML=='' || ele.innerHTML=='&nbsp;') {
   if(red.value=='0') {
    ele.innerHTML='X';
    ele.style.color='red';
    red.value='1';
    pl=document.getElementById('pl1');
   } else {
    ele.innerHTML='O';
    ele.style.color='blue';
    red.value='0';
    pl=document.getElementById('pl2');
   }
   pl.value+=br.toString()+',';
   checkWinner();
  }
 }
}

function checkWinner() {
  var pl1=document.getElementById('pl1').value.split(',');
  var pl2=document.getElementById('pl2').value.split(',');
  pl1.pop(); pl2.pop();
  pl1=pl1.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
  pl2=pl2.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
  var arr=[];
  arr.push('1,2,3');
  arr.push('4,5,6');
  arr.push('7,8,9');
  arr.push('1,4,7');
  arr.push('2,5,8');
  arr.push('3,6,9');
  arr.push('1,5,9');
  arr.push('3,5,7');
  //var res1=pl1.join();
  //var res2=pl2.join();
  for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
   //for testing
   var qq=arr[i].split(',');
   var tot=0;
   for (var x=0;x<pl1.length;x++) {
    if(pl1[x]==qq[0]) {
     tot+=1;
    } else if(pl1[x]==qq[1]) {
     tot+=1;
    } else if(pl1[x]==qq[2]) {
     tot+=1
    }
    if(tot==3) {
     var rr=parseInt(document.getElementById('rezPl1').innerHTML)+1;
     document.getElementById('rezPl1').innerHTML=rr.toString();
     drawResult(arr[i]);
     return;
    }
   }
   tot=0;
   for (var x=0;x<pl2.length;x++) {
    if(pl2[x]==qq[0]) {
     tot+=1;
    } else if(pl2[x]==qq[1]) {
     tot+=1;
    } else if(pl2[x]==qq[2]) {
     tot+=1
    }
    if(tot==3) {
     var rr=parseInt(document.getElementById('rezPl2').innerHTML)+1;
     document.getElementById('rezPl2').innerHTML=rr.toString();
     drawResult(arr[i]);
     return;
    }
   }
  }
}

function drawResult(result) {
 var pp=result.split(',');
 document.getElementById('ovr').value='1';
 var tbl=document.getElementById('xo');
 for(var i=0;i<pp.length;i++) {
  var x=parseInt(pp[i]);
  if(x>=1 && x<=3) {
   tbl.rows[0].cells[x-1].style.backgroundColor='yellow';
  }
  if(x>=4 && x<=6) {
   tbl.rows[1].cells[x-4].style.backgroundColor='yellow';
  }
  if(x>=7 && x<=9) {
   tbl.rows[2].cells[x-7].style.backgroundColor='yellow';
  }
 }
}

function clearRes() {
 document.getElementById('pl1').value='';
 document.getElementById('pl2').value='';
 document.getElementById('ovr').value='0';
 var tbl=document.getElementById('xo');
 for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
  for(var x=0;x<3;x++) {
   tbl.rows[i].cells[x].innerHTML='';
   tbl.rows[i].cells[x].style.backgroundColor='transparent';
  }
 }
}

function startGame() {
 document.getElementById('tdImeX').innerHTML=document.getElementById('txtX').value;
 document.getElementById('tdImeO').innerHTML=document.getElementById('txtO').value;
 document.getElementById('pl1').value='';
 document.getElementById('pl2').value='';
 document.getElementById('ovr').value='0';
 document.getElementById('red').value='0';
 document.getElementById('divLoad').style.display='none';
 document.getElementById('divGame').style.display='block';
}

function endGame() {
 document.getElementById('tdImeX').innerHTML='';
 document.getElementById('txtX').value='';
 document.getElementById('tdImeO').innerHTML='';
 document.getElementById('txtO').value='';
 document.getElementById('pl1').value='';
 document.getElementById('pl2').value='';
 document.getElementById('ovr').value='0';
 document.getElementById('red').value='0';
 document.getElementById('divLoad').style.display='block';
 document.getElementById('divGame').style.display='none';
 document.getElementById('txtX').focus();
}
```

```css
body, html {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body
{
 font: normal 14px "Trebuchet MS";
 color: black;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.wrapper
{
 display: block;
 width: 250px;
 border:solid 1px orange;
 margin: 30px auto;
 padding: 10px;
}
.inbox
{
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
#xo
{
 display: block;
 border:solid 1px gray;
 width: 94px;
 height: 94px;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px silver;
 margin:0 auto;
}
#xo tr td
{
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-right: solid 1px gray;
 border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: black;
}
#xo tr td:last-child
{
 border-right:none;
}
#xo tr:last-child td:last-child
{
 border-bottom: none;
}

#tblrez
{
 margin: 30px 0px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
#tblrez td
{
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 18px;
 border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
 width: 50%;
}
#tblrez td:first-child {border-right: solid 1px gray;}
#rezPl1, #rezPl2
{
 border-bottom: none !important;
 font-size: 22px;
 color: navy;
 font-weight: bold;
}
#rezPl2
{
 color: firebrick;
}

input[type="button"]
{
 border:solid 1px navy;
 background-color: lightblue;
 color: black;
 padding: 4px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 4px;
}
input[type="button"]:hover
{
 background-color: firebrick;
 color:white;
}

.box
{
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="pl1" names="pl1" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" id="pl2" name="pl2" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" id="red" name="red" value="0">
 <input type="hidden" id="ovr" name="ovr" value="0">
 <div class="wrapper">
 <div id="divLoad" style="display:block;" class="box">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellspacing="0" class="inbox">
   <tr>
    <td style="color:firebrick;font-weight:bold;">X</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtX" value="" placeholder="Player 1" autofocus />
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="color:navy;font-weight:bold;">O</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtO" value="" placeholder="Player 2" />
   </tr>
  </table>
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Start game" onclick="startGame();">
 </div>
 <div id="divGame" style="display:none;" class="box">
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="xo">
     </table>
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tblrez">
      <tr>
       <td id="tdImeX">X</td>
       <td id="tdImeO">O</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="rezPl1">0</td>
       <td id="rezPl2">0</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <input type="button" value="New game" onclick="clearRes();" />
     <input type="button" value="End game" onclick="endGame();">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To make sure nothing happens when the user clicks on a square that
   already contains a marker:

**- remove the onclick attribute from the clicked TD element in the squareClicked function.**

**Answer:**
Create a variable to check if the `td` has child element.

```
var sqrStatus = document.getElementById(sqr.id).childElementCount;
```

After create a logic to remove the `onclick` attribute if `td` has child element.

```
if (sqrStatus == 1) {
    document.getElementById(sqr.id).removeAttribute('onclick');
} else if (sqrStatus == 0) {
    alert('You clicked square ' + sqr.id);
}
```

**- add the onclick attribute to each TD when setting a new game**

**Answer:** When you click new game, everything reset and you need to add the `onclick` attribute to all `td` elements. You have the following block code. Locate it and replace it with following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tdNodes.length; i++) {
    removeNode = tdNodes[i].firstChild;
    if (removeNode) {
        removeNode.parentNode.removeChild(removeNode);
    }
    document.getElementById('c' + i).setAttribute('onclick', 'squareClicked(this)')
    document.getElementById('c' + i).setAttribute('class', '');
}
```

**- remove the onclick attribute from the each TD that has a marker when loading a game.**

**Answer:** Create a variable to look for `td` elements which as `onclick` attribute and then run the for loop to perform the remove all process. Add the following block code inside the `loadGame` class.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        var childElementStatus = document.getElementById('c' + i).childElementCount;
        if (childElementStatus != 0) {
            checkMarker = document.getElementById('c' + i).firstElementChild.className;

            if (checkMarker != "") {
                checkMarker = document.getElementById('c' + i).removeAttribute('onclick');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Modify the squareClicked function so that it will:

**- make sure the square does not have an X or O in it**

**Answer:** You need three variables to achieve this. One of the required variable is already created and two other variables: a) to check TurnO and b) to check TurnX variable. Add the following block code into your `squareClicked` function.

```
var xTurn = document.getElementById('X').className;
var oTurn = document.getElementById('O').className;
```

**- determine which player's turn it is**

**- create a new DIV element with the correct class and place it in the 
      clicked TD (don't use innerHTML)**

**- change the current player**

**Answer:** Check with following logic the user's turn. Add the following code into your `squareClicked` function.

```
    if (xTurn != "" && sqrStatus == 0) {
            newEl = document.createElement('DIV');
            newEl.className = 'X-marker';
            document.getElementById(sqr.id).appendChild(newEl);
            xTurn = document.getElementById('X').className = "";
            oTurn = document.getElementById('O').className = "current-player";
        } else if (oTurn != "" && sqrStatus == 0) {
            newEl = document.createElement('DIV');
            newEl.className = 'O-marker';
            document.getElementById(sqr.id).appendChild(newEl);
            oTurn = document.getElementById('O').className = "";
            xTurn = document.getElementById('X').className = "current-player";
        }
}
```

3. In the setBanner function, check to see if a banner has already been set
   and delete the old one before setting the new one.

**Answer:** You need logic here to check if the `h1` element is exist, and if exist delete and recreate it but if not exist then create it. Replace the following code with the `setBanner` function.

```
function setBanner() {
    var banner = prompt('Banner Text?');
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.textContent = banner;
    //var body = document.querySelector('body');
    var playerDiv = document.querySelector('#players');
    var h1Status = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName('h1').length) {
        document.body.insertBefore(h1, playerDiv);
    } else {
        var element = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
        element[0].parentNode.removeChild(element[0]);
        document.body.insertBefore(h1, playerDiv);
    }
}
```

**Also follow the following instructions:**

Add in the newGame function:

```
document.getElementById('X').className = 'current-player';
document.getElementById('O').className = '';
if (document.getElementsByTagName('h1').length) {
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
    element[0].parentNode.removeChild(element[0]);
}
```